# Change "Top tag" to rely on number of answers per tag

Tags: feature-request, tags, profile-page

When viewing your profile on stackoverflow, there is a field that displays the "Top tag". As far as I can see, this is based on the rep gained in that particular tag.

I think it should rather rely on the number of answers one made in a particular tag, because the rating by rep might yield false results. As an example, my TT is [iOS], while I've only made one answer related to that tag. [iOS] is not really relevant to me, as my field of expertise is [autoit], the tag that is related to most of my answers/comments.

This suggestion could also be extended to: "The tag with the most answers with a rep > 0."

Opinions on that?

Comment: Yeah, about your last sentence, that's a great idea, because spammy tags with millions and billions of spam and more spam shouldn't count. Like spam tags about spam meat or just Internet spam, they should all be down-voted, so the tags won't go all the way up.

Comment: I totally agree

Comment: Yes, in my case my main field is C# but I've got "Html" as top tag because of 31 thumbs up for an answer regarding how to configure Notepad+ intellisense for editing Html. The question was tagged as "notepad, html" so I became an "expert" in Html.